# Anime where the main character enters a game he plays and uses his knowledge of the game to his advantage

Tags: story-identification, anime

The basic plot was the main character was transferred to a game that he plays. He isn't overpowered but he does have knowledge of the game.

One thing I remember distinctly is that people in that game don't know how to "Counter" and he uses this to defeat a boss and also he knows some other mechanics as well. On top of that, the monsters that were originally in the game are downgraded in a sense (like, lets say you find a pidgey in Route 1, but people there call and believe it's a pidgeot).

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this? And did you see it on TV or online?

Comment: Was it "counter" or "critical hit" they didn't know how to do? Because I recall reading a manga where the MC was the only one that could reliably critical, because you just "move your hand the right way", while everyone else thought it was random. Not that I recall the name offhand.

Comment: If it was a manga/web novel rather than an anime, then "Kono Sekai ga Game da to, Ore dake ga Shitteiru" fits the bill.

Comment: @qazmlpok yes now that I mentioned it is critical hit

Comment: I haven't been able to find the series I was thinking of, but I don't think it was adapted to anime. Was this definitely an anime, and not just a manga? Do you recall when you watched this? And do you have any idea if this was airing at the same time you were watching it (i.e. a simulpub release)?

Comment: I don't really remember if it was aring the same time I was watching.. but it was definitely an anime .. nad I watched in 3 4 months ago I think

Answer (score 2):

This could very well be: [Isekai Kenja No Tensei Musou](https://myanimelist.net/manga/128991/Isekai_Kenja_no_Tensei_Musou__Game_no_Chishiki_de_Isekai_Saikyou)

> A young man unfortunately died in the modern era, he reincarnated in another world under the name "Eldo," which also happened to be a world similar to a VRMMO game that he used to play in his previous life. However, it's a world where he knows the "basic skills." Eldo became a level 1 adventurer, playing as a "novice," but he knows the world better than anyone, and this is because of the "data he knows." Will the reincarnation in this world make him strong?

From the Manga in chapter 2, while joining the guild and overpowering the tester through a critical hit, the receptionist later remarks in chapter 3 that "using a miracle strike means you're an expert". Also during this chapter, Eldo is looking through a book of requests where the danger rating F-SS seems skewed as standard monsters are rated higher than they were in the game.

Now the thing is, that I can find no reference to an anime by that name, but I swear I recall seeing one episode (and only the one) that fits the timeline above that this relates to. I remember the obnoxious receptionist and seem to recall the Guild master/tester giving the thumbs up after the assessment from a pile of rocks (which is different from the way the manga shows it)

Answer (score -1):

Is it possibly the anime-inspired webcomic "Erfworld"?

> Erfworld was a story-driven fantasy/comedy webcomic and independently
> published graphic novel about a master strategy gamer summoned into
> and stuck inside a wargame
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erfworld

Comment: This fits the "stuck inside a game" trope, but aside from that do any of the actual plot points mentioned fit the description?